# Which levels do salvage droids unlock?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

In Tiny Death Star, which new levels can be unlocked from the salvage droids (and from which destinations)?

When Kashyyk was my gold destination, I unlocked the Kashyyk Shack from it. I haven't unlocked and other levels using the salvage droids, but I thought someone else on here reported unlocking Chiss Hospital by sending a bronze droid to Kashyyk. Can anyone confirm this? When I click on the question mark next to Kashyyk, it only shows me one level to be unlocked, and that one looks like the Kashyyk Shack.

Answer (score 2):

Kashyyyk unlocks 2 levels - Kashyyyk Arms and Kashyyyk Shack. I can confirm this because I've gotten both. From Endor, I've unlocked the Endor Adventure. I believe Endor Arms can be unlocked through here too. So based on this, I would suggest that a Chiss soundalike area would unlock Csilla Apts and Chiss Hsp. Hope this helps.